# setCenter position resetting when loading/unloading subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, subview

This has been driving me nuts all day! I am a relative beginner at objective-c, so excuse my mistakes!

What I want to do is assign some buttons a random x position on the screen on a view, this is the code I'm using:

```
int screenwidth = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 100);
[_Game0_Button1 setCenter:(CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(screenwidth) + 50, _Game0_Button1.center.y))];
```

While this works fine, when a subview loads or unloads the new positions that are assigned are reset back to their original positions, such as:

```
[self addChildViewController: GamePausedVC];

GamePausedVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
GamePausedVC.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview: GamePausedVC.view];
[GamePausedVC didMoveToParentViewController: self];

[GamePausedVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[GamePausedVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[GamePausedVC removeFromParentViewController];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an array of your random positions and reset the button positions in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would be one way to solve the problem. I was really just wondering if this was normal for positions to be reset on a subview loading/unloading?

Comment: Hmm.. even resetting the button positions in viewDidAppear doesn't work as that is when I am loading the subviews. I can't delay the change in location otherwise that would look terrible, nor can I delay the subviews. What should I do?

Comment: Try the new view controller call `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.